# Accessing another repository from within GitHub Actions without using PAT

Tags: github, github-actions

Within a GitHub Actions workflow in repository `A` we are trying to download release assets from another private repository `B`. Therefore the runner (running in a workflow in repo `A`) needs to authenticate against repository `B`.

There seem to be 2 possible solutions for that:

1. Create a private access token (PAT)
2. Create a GitHub application and use that for authenticating

Since we do not want this setup to be dependent on individual users, option 1) seems like the wrong approach. But we somehow got stuck with option 2). What we did so far:

1. Create a GitHub application (not oauth, since it should be independent of the user)
2. Grant all permissions for repositories to this app
3. Install the app in our organisation
4. Generate an app private key and create a JWT token following the documentation [here](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#authenticating-as-a-github-app)
5. Sending a `curl` request with this generated JWT token, like

   ```
   curl -i -X POST \
     -H "Authorization: Bearer YOUR_JWT" \
     -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
     https://api.github.com/app/installations/:installation_id/access_tokens
   ```

But this request always gives us a `401`.

So first question is: are we on the right track here? Second question would be: how can we make this work?

It also puzzles us that we would have to re-create the JWT token with every workflow run (since we cannot use a long enough expiration time), and would rather like to have something that can be put into the secrets store of the workflow.